# Can't find long/lat using google maps api on android

Tags: android, google-maps

Just messing around/trying to learn with the google maps api. For some reason when I pass longitude and latitude from my app to google I keep getting  a message reading that google maps can't find the coordinates. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have that problem, it is almost *always* because I have the latitude and longitude backwards.